# Select rows where a column is not null if multiple values or null if 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing titles and values.

For a distinct title, I want to retrieve all not null values, except if this title only has a NULL value.

A sample of my table looks like this:

```
Title    Value          
---------------
ex1      8
ex1      9
ex1      NULL
ex2      8
ex2      NULL
ex3      NULL
```

In this example I want my desired output would look like this:

```
Libelle  TPO_code   
--------------------        
ex1      8
ex1      9
ex2      8
ex3      NULL
```

I can achieve retrieving all but NULL values with the following request but I am blocked for the case a title has only a NULL value :

```
select distinct Title, Value 
from mytable
where Value is not null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT T.Title
,       T.Value 
FROM    mytable T
WHERE   T.Value IS NOT NULL
    OR  NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT  NULL
                        FROM    mytable T2
                        WHERE   T2.Value IS NOT NULL
                            AND T2.Title = T1.Title
                    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using the unions if you want and try this:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (Title CHAR(4) NOT NULL, Value INT NULL);

INSERT INTO @myTable (Title, Value)
VALUES ('ex1', 8)
,      ('ex1', 9)
,      ('ex1', NULL)
,      ('ex2', 8)
,      ('ex2', NULL)
,      ('ex3', NULL);

SELECT      DISTINCT
            T1.Title
,           T2.Value
  FROM      @myTable T1
  LEFT JOIN @myTable T2 ON  T2.Title = T1.Title
                       AND  T2.Value IS NOT NULL;
```

I'd suggest trying all of these options against the shape of your real data to find the most efficient version.  Is also worth spending some time checking indexes etc to make these quicker.

Comment: Nice find, I did not think of using a join for this. Usually its the first that i try because its often most efficient +1

Comment: @GuidoG - Thanks.  Is just another option.  With out knowing the shape of the data/indexes/etc. its always a case of try them all out and see whats the fastest.  Was trying to think of a way to do this without hitting the table twice - I'll post my other option in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a union and a subquery

```
declare @t table (Title varchar(10), Value int)
insert into @t (Title, Value)
values ('ex1', 8), ('ex1', 9), ('ex1', null), ('ex2', 8), ('ex2', null), ('ex3', null)

-- first get all rows with Value different from null
select t.Title,
       t.Value
from   @t t
where  t.Value is not null

union 

-- now also get all rows with just one row and where that row has null in value
select t.Title,
       t.Value
from   @t t
where  t.Title in ( select t2.title from @t t2 group by t2.Title having count(t2.Title) = 1 )
and    t.Value is null
```

this will return this result

```
Title   Value   
-----   -----   
ex1     8   
ex1     9   
ex2     8   
ex3     null
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (Title CHAR(4) NOT NULL, Value INT NULL);

INSERT INTO @myTable (Title, Value)
VALUES ('ex1', 8)
,      ('ex1', 9)
,      ('ex1', NULL)
,      ('ex2', 8)
,      ('ex2', NULL)
,      ('ex3', NULL);

-- Original
SELECT      DISTINCT
            T1.Title
,           T2.Value
  FROM      @myTable T1
  LEFT JOIN @myTable T2 ON  T2.Title = T1.Title
                       AND  T2.Value IS NOT NULL;

-- Common Table Expression example
WITH cte AS
    (SELECT *
     ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Title
ORDER BY Value DESC) RN
       FROM @myTable)
SELECT  cte.Title
,       cte.Value
  FROM  cte
 WHERE  RN = 1
   OR   cte.Value IS NOT NULL
```

If you run through a common table expression and assign row numbers, you can ensure at least one row per "Title" without the multiple table hits.  If you run the execution plans on the two side by side I'm seeing  a saving on the cte version over the join.  Will depend on how much data is going in though as the sort may become more expensive than the join - although the join version requires a sort for the distinct.

Give them a try on real data and get some timings.  let me know if this helps.

Comment: On my data it is faster (~10sec on 3mins) to use this option although it gives me only rank 1. I adjusted it to have all ranks except null ranks if rank for a title > 2. Thanks for your time !

Comment: Oops, missed the bottom line of my code.  Have another go and see how that compares to what you've adjusted.  Being able to work the solution from partial answer is usually more useful because it shows you've understood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE (Title, Value)
AS
(          
SELECT 'ex1', 8    UNION ALL
SELECT 'ex1', 9    UNION ALL
SELECT 'ex1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ex2', 8    UNION ALL
SELECT 'ex2', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ex3', NULL

)
,CTe2
AS
(
SELECT Title, Value, COUNT(Title)OVER(PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY Title) cnt
FROM CTE
)
SELECT  Title, 
        Value 
FROM CTe2 WHERE ISNULL(Value,1) <> 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  Title,
        Value 
FROM CTe2 WHERE cnt =1
```

Result

```
Title   Value
-------------
ex1      8
ex1      9
ex2      8
ex3      NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest below solution for your problem,

```
select title,value from mytable where id is not null
union
select title,value from (
  select title,value, dense_rank() over (partition by title order by value)  rank from mytable)
where rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      
    DISTINCT a.Title,           
             b.Value   
FROM      
    mytable a   
LEFT JOIN 
    mytable b 
ON  
    a.Title = b.Title 
AND  
    b.Value IS NOT NULL;
```